# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error IIS

Tags: .net, iis-express

First of all, there is no experience on IIS or .net. So sorry for the mistakes in the question I asked. Our customer wants to serve application via IIS. But here we run into a problem. Our application running on a Windows machine will always auto scale. That's why we want to use a Shared storage. Like AWS's EFS for example. Our problem here is as follows:

[image]

When we specify a physical path as above, we encounter the error in the title. The error is like this:
[image]

but I do not encounter any problem when I mount this path by specifying it this way.

```
\\192.168.0.143\wwwroot
```

[image]

As I said above, I don't have much knowledge in this field. I would appreciate it if you could make a clear explanation.

Comment: 1. You should add `iis-express` tag to this question, as that's totally irrelevant. 2. Since you set the physical path to a file share, have you configured a domain user as application pool identity? That domain user must have at read permission on this file share.

Comment: Thank you for correcting first. I corrected the tag. Yes I set user and give all permissions.  Actually, I found a solution here. It was fine when I used this syntax \\192.168.0.143\!\wwwroot instead of \\192.168.0.143\wwwroot. What is the difference? both can serve. but the one without the exclamation point is, for example, when I click on explorer, the application folder does not open, it opens from the other.

Answer (score 1):

The error code 0x80070003 you are getting because of the permission is not enough to the web.config file. could you try assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the project root folder.

Here is the link you can refer for more detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x80070003

Comment: @j4nus from where you got this  exclamation path location

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to folder permissions to user IIS_IUSRS
Do the following:

1. Right click on the folder where published files are
2. Selecting the tab "security"
3. Finally add the user IIS_IUSRS - don't forget the i in front of USRS and don't write an "e" as in USERS

And your error is gone.